# Basic Algorithmic Trading Strategy

Tags: stocks, trading, stock-analysis, online-trading

I was searching the web for basic algorithmic trading concepts and came across the following article. http://www.investopedia.com/articles/active-trading/101014/basics-algorithmic-trading-concepts-and-examples.asp

There is a section of the article which refers to simple trade criteria.

"Suppose a trader follows these simple trade criteria:

- Buy 50 shares of a stock when its 50-day moving average goes above
  the 200-day moving average
- Sell shares of the stock when its 50-day    moving average goes below
  the 200-day moving average"

Does this seem like a reasonable basic trading algorithm strategy? If not, can you point me to a better one?

I find it strange that they are suggesting to buy when the stock is up, and sell when the stock is down.

Comment: it's the nature of averages.  when the near term average breaks the long term average barrier, tomorrow the long term average will be a little higher as a result.  When the near term average falls to break the long term average barrier you'll probably still be at a profit when you sell even though you're selling while it's falling.

Comment: Generally algorithms used in algorithmic trading are proprietary. So you willn't find them online. You have to develop your own.

Comment: Yes, it's a reasonable basic trading algorithm strategy - but if your question is "is it profitable?" then the answer is no (you may find backtests proving otherwise online: they are probably flawed)...

Comment: The big guys have teams working on creating the algorithms and coding it. They utilize the best computers/ latest technology and are generally connected to the exchanges using direct lines. You are going to have a tough time competing with those algorithms.

Comment: @edocetirwi I consistently hear people saying it is not worth getting involved in algorithmic trading. But, I don't have to beat the big guys to make money. I can just beat everyone else that isn't using their own algorithms. Do you know the joke... I don't have to outrun the bear. I just have to outrun you.

Comment: @assylias Thanks. I have read elsewhere that it has major downsides visible with back testing.

Comment: @DumbCoder The online resource seems to be Quantopian https://www.quantopian.com/posts.

Comment: @ADH Yea, I agree. If you know what you are doing, everything works out :)

Comment: @assylias why do you say algorithmic trading isn't profitable? If it wasn't then why are the institutional investors using them?

Comment: @NuWin I only said that this specific strategy is not profitable. There definitely are profitable algorithmic strategies...

Comment: @assylias Ahh I see. Then I would have to agree. Simply trading this crossover with the averages is not a solid trading strategy.

Comment: @ADH you should check out quant.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This strategy is called trading the 'Golden Cross' if the 50 day SMA moves above the 200 day, or the 'Death Cross' when the 50 day SMA moves below the 200 day SMA. Long-term indicators carry more weight than shorter-term indicators, and this cross, in a positive direction signals a change in momentum of the stock. You will not catch the very bottom using this method, but there is a better chance that you will catch a move near the beginning of a longer-term trend.

[Golden Cross Information - Zacks](http://finance.zacks.com/golden-cross-mean-financial-terms-9519.html)

Comment: What ode2k describes is the essence of the MACD approach. [Here is the S&P](http://stockcharts.com/h-sc/ui?s=SPY&p=D&yr=2&mn=0&dy=0&id=p38155111758) graphed using this method.

Comment: [Here is the documentation](http://stockcharts.com/school/doku.php?st=macd&id=chart_school:technical_indicators:moving_average_convergence_divergence_macd) on MACD.